# How to replace all matched (regex) back to the list to remove them without TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace

My file has differents urls:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/validagain
www.example.com/search?q=jsdajasj;kdas     --> trying to get rid off
www.example.com/anothervalid
```

I was able to isolate the `/search` using regex:

```
import re

generate_links = re.compile('http://(.*)') #compile all http links
generate_links2 = re.compile('(.*)/eng/(.*)') #compile all english url
with open ("VAC\queue.txt", "r") as queued_list, open('newqueue.txt','w') as queued_list_updated:
    for links in queued_list:
        url = ""
        services_url = ""
        valid_url = ""
        match = generate_links2.search(links)
        if match is not None:
            url = match.group()
            generate_links3 = re.compile('(.*)/services/(.*)') #compile all services links
            match2 = generate_links3.search(links)
            if match2 is not None:
                services_url = match2.group()
                print services_url
                generate_links4 = re.compile('(.*)/search?(.*)') #compiled error links
                match3 = generate_links4.search(links) #matched all error links
```

**But how do I use `match3` variable back to `services_url` to remove itself or be replaced?**

So the **expected results** would be:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/validagain
www.example.com/anothervalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of url containing 'search?' try :

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open() as in, open() as out:
    cured_url = [l for l in in.readlines() if 'search?' not in l]

    for url in cured_url:
        print(url, file=out)
```